# How to extract a region from an android Bitmap

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap, android-canvas

I am stuck with the following problem:

I have an android Bitmap and a set of 4 coordinates, representing a rectangle. However, the rectangle may be rotated. For example I may have the coordinates 0/50, 50/0, 100/50, 50/100. Therefore I cannot simply use the Canvas drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint) function because I cannot specify such coordinates in a rect Object. What would be the best way to extract such a rectangle?

Comment: Have a look at the Lunar lander sample code that comes with the SDK. In LunarView.java search for 'rotate'. That will show you how they spin the drawing of the spaceship.

Answer (score 1):

Can you calculate what angle your rectangle is tilted? In that case you can rotate the canvas:

```
canvas.rotate(angle, px, py);
```

where px and py are the coordinates for the center of the rectangle.

And then do the drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint).

Comment: I can calculate the angle. But how do I translate the points I had previously calculated to the ones corresponding to the rotated canvas? In my experience the mapPoints function of a Matrix does not really work. At least that is what I experienced when rotating a Image with a rotate Matrix and tried to map the original points afterwards. Still, might be worth another try, guess I will see if it works.

Comment: I think I missunderstood how rotate on canvas works. So with this is can rotate the Canvas itself. In my understanding this would caus my rectangle which was previously skewed to be now alligned. But I cannot see how it solves the problem that I am not able to specify the coordinates of the rectangle I want to cut out in the first place. @NickT from my first glance at the LunarView sample this seems to be what is done there too. They have an anligned image and want it to be drawn rotated by some degree. I on the other hand want it the other way around in a way.